# File of words to a linked-list of words

Tags: c

I'd like to get a review for the function `build_list()` which reads a file containing words (separated by spaces) and returns a linked-list of words:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
    char* word;
    struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List {
    ListNode *head;
    ListNode *tail;
} List;

List* build_list(char* fileName)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    assert(file != NULL);

    List* list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    assert(list != NULL);
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;

    char c;
    int word_size = 1;
    char* word = malloc(word_size);
    int word_count = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        assert(!ferror(file));

        while (c != ' ' && c != EOF)
        {
            if (word_count == word_size)
            {
                word_size += 1;
                word = realloc(word, word_size);
                assert(word != NULL);
            }

            word[word_count++] = c;

            c = fgetc(file);
            assert(!ferror(file));
        }

        word = realloc(word, word_size + 1);
        word[word_size] = '\0';

        ListNode *node = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        assert(node != NULL);
        node->next = NULL;
        node->word = word;

        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            list->head = node;
            list->tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail->next = node;
            list->tail = node;
        }

        if (c == EOF)
            break;

        word_count = 0;
        word_size = 1;
        word = malloc(word_size);

    }

    free(word);

    assert(!ferror(file));

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is very readable. Nice work! I think it could be simplified a bit.

I'll add that I agree completely with what @erichamion has suggested.

### Minimize What Can Go Wrong

The function does a lot of allocations. Anytime you allocate memory, it can fail, and you need to deal with that. It's better to not have to allocate memory in the first place. You can remove one allocation by having the caller pass in a reference to a `List`:

```
int build_list(List* list, char* fileName)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return ERR_NO_SUCH_FILE; // this is something defined by your code
    }
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    //... etc.
```

In this scenario, the caller would do something like this:

```
List wordList;
int err = build_list(&wordList, "/path/to/word/file");
```

Since `wordList` is allocated on the stack and not dynamically, it can't fail. (Well, it could fail if your stack is too deep, but that's a much less common scenario than `malloc` or `realloc` failing.)

### Break It Down Again

You've made a function to create a list from a file, but you can break that process down even further. You've got a loop where you read a word from the file, then you have code where you put that word into the list. Those could be 2 different functions:

```
int readWord(FILE* file, char** word)
{
    int word_size = 1;
    int word_count = 0;
    int c = fgetc(file);
    while (c != ' ' && c != EOF)
    {
        if (word_count == word_size)
        {
            word_size += 1;
            *word = realloc(*word, word_size);
            assert(*word != NULL);
        }

        (*word)[word_count++] = c;

        c = fgetc(file);
        assert(!ferror(file));
    }

    *word = realloc(word, word_size + 1);
    (*word)[word_size] = '\0';
    
    if (c == EOF) {
        return c;
    }
    return NO_ERR;
}
```

I'll be honest - I don't like this loop a lot. There's a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293475/reading-c-file-line-by-line-using-fgetc) about reading a file 1 character at a time using `fgetc()`. If you can control the format of the input, it would be better to have line endings between the words and use `fgets()`, or something similar. The constant allocations and reallocations are going to be very slow and are very error prone, too. If you know of the maximum word size, you could just allocate the maximum once, read the string, and then if memory's really constrained, allocate the actual amount needed and copy the string. In fact, if you did that, you could re-use the buffer during reading.

Next, you could make adding a node to the list a separate function:

```
int add_word_to_list(List* list, char* word)
{
    int result = NO_ERR;
    ListNode* newNode = malloc (sizeof(ListNode));
    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        result = ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY; // or whatever you want to use
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->word = word;
        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            list->head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail.next = newNode;
        }
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can call the above 2 functions like this:

```
char* word = malloc(1);
int err = read_word(file, word);
while (err == NO_ERR)
{
    err = add_word_to_list(&list, &word);
    if (err == NO_ERR)
    {
        word = malloc(1);
        err = read_word(file, &word);
    }
}
free (word);
return err;
```

Comment: This isn't C++, so `List& list` won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I thought C99 supported references. I'll update it to use a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

`assert()` isn't meant for runtime errors like an invalid filename. It's meant to aid in debugging by catching logical errors. Essentially, it says, "There should be *no possible way* this statement can be false. If it is false, something about this program is invalid, so I need to blow up."

A good use of `assert()` here would be:

```
List* build_list(char* fileName)
{
    assert(fileName && fileName[0]);
    // Alternately (more verbose, but maybe more clear):
    assert(fileName != NULL && fileName[0] != '\0');
    // Another alternative, which gives a helpful message
    // if it fails
    assert(fileName && fileName[0]
        && "build_list(char* fileName) was given a null or empty fileName");
```

This way, if you write a function somewhere else that passes a null filename into build_list, you'll get notified of the programming error.

A runtime error such as a missing file is better handled by returning some kind of error. You could return NULL on error, or you could take a List* (or List**) as an argument and return an integer result (0 for success is typical).